# Edit the [tensorflow] tag excerpt

Tags: discussion, tag-excerpt

If you go to [tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow) and see the tag excerpt, `**IMPORTANT**` is not being formatted as bold. And if you hover over the tag in a question, It won't show as bold there too.

[image]

Because formatting is not supported in tag excerpts [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr5SK.png) while editing the tag excerpt. So we should just edit that part out, also caps looks like an exaggeration. Should we edit that out too?

Comment: Formatting is not possible in the excerpt. In the full tag wiki formatting is possible.

Comment: @BDL should we then just edit out the `**Important**` to just `Important`?

Comment: I would do it. It still highlights the word somehow.

Comment: @BDL looks ugly, un-formatted to me. If tag excerpts don't support formatting then why did it went there in the first place?

Comment: [Editing also states it's plain-text only](https://i.imgur.com/7iTTWNn.png).

Comment: @Zoe edited my question. Suggest an edit to the wiki.

Comment: It's still not formatted yet. Is there any progress in this field ?